# Javascript defining array. "arrayception"

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a list of "items" in a canvas game. For example, an array named list. Each element must contain the information about each item. First element will contain something different. I will remove first one with 'shift()' command. Like :

```
list.shift(); 
list[0]['name']
list[0]['id']
list[0]['x']
list[0]['y']
list[1]['name']
list[1]['id']
list[1]['x']
list[1]['y']
```

but i don't know how to define something like this. normally i define arrays like

`{"name" : xx, "id" : 5 ... }`

but this works like :

```
list['name']
list['id']
```

Comment: `{ ... }` is not an array, it's an object (literal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no associative arrays in javascript.
so for instance , when you do

```
var _array = []
_array["field1"] ="value";
```

you are actually adding a property to the _array object .

```
_array.field1 = value <=> _array["field1"] ="value";
```

so if you want to create a collection of objects , do

```
var collection =[];
var myObject = {"field1":"value1"};
collection.push(myObject);
```

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
var list = [];
list[0] = {name: 'xx', id: 0, /*etc*/};
list[1] = {name: 'yy', id: 1, /*etc*/};
```

it creates an array of objects. You can use it like this:

```
var first = list.shift();
first.name; //=> xx
//or
var first = list[0];
first.name; //=> xx
```

**Note**: using `{...}` (Object literal) creates an `Object`, not an `Array`. An array can be created using an Array literal: `[...]`. Although an object is sometimes said to be an *Associative Array*, it is not an Array object, so things like `{...}.shift()` will not work for Objects.

Comment: how can i send this through websockets using JSON.stringify ?

Comment: You can just serialize the list object

Comment: for the example of my answer: `var liststr = JSON.stringify(list)` returns `"[{"name":"xx","id":0},{"name":"yy","id":1}]"`, `var list2 = JSON.parse(liststr)` converts the string back to the array of obects. The string can be sent through websockets I suppose, that's out of the realm of this question.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i will look through it a bit. by the way i have learnt that [] is array, {} is object. thanks. so i will define objects in [] and send that.